# Is there a word for "international or domestic travel"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I'm looking for a word that represents "type of travel" where that type is either domestic or international.

Does this word exist?

Comment: Since 'domestic' and 'international' are each other's opposite, I guess you're left with just 'travel' with no specific qualifier.  Sorry if that's not the answer you expected - I just mean there might not be any satisfying one.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? If this could have been worded better please give an example.

Comment: Just for the avoidance of doubt, downvote was not mine. Commented only.

Comment: @Alain: Didn't expect it was. I'm not an English scholar or anything, just trying to find a word. So if there's a better way to phrase this question I'd like to know so I can make use of it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I think *Travel* is the word and *domestic* and *international* are the types. Is the question a rhetoric?

[EDIT]: Before down-voting please realize that I might not have understood the question properly, so you could consider commenting before you down-vote.

Comment: The word "type" seems too generic.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it's a perfectly sensible answer to the question in the title that didn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, if worded a little poorly.

What you're asking, I guess, is what set the words 'international' and 'domestic' belong to when referring to travel. I suppose the answer might be *destination*, as you are either going somewhere within your home country or somewhere not in your home country.

Comment: More "destinations" that more or less work with travel: Country; urban; suburban; rural; interstate; Brazilian; beach. Alternatives to "destination" could be locale, area, zone, scope.